# Missing pagination dropdown icon using Angular ui grid

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-grid

I am developing a table with pagination using Angular ui-grid. But somehow I am missing the drop arrow from the pagination dropdown as you can see in the following picture.

[image]

When I click it, it opens like dropdown, but I need the down arrow to indicate that its a dropdown.

I am using following css libraries

```
<link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="libs/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/paper.bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Style" href="libs/angular/ui-grid/3.0.7/ui-grid.min.css">
```

I config gridOptions as following

```
paginationPageSizes: [10, 20, 50],
paginationPageSize: 10,
data: 'historyData',
enableCellSelection: true,
enableFiltering: true,
enableHorizontalScrollbar: 1,
treeRowHeaderAlwaysVisible: false,
showTreeRowHeader: true,
enableGridMenu: true,
exporterMenuCsv: false,
exporterMenuPdf: false,
```

Below is my html code

```
<div class="container">

<div id="gridDiv" 
    style="-webkit-animation: slideInRight 0.3s; -moz-animation: slideInRight 0.3s; animation: slideInRight 0.3s;">
    <div id="historyGrid" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-edit
        ui-grid-cellnav ui-grid-move-columns ui-grid-resize-columns
        ui-grid-save-state ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-pinning
        ui-grid-grouping ui-grid-exporter class="grid"></div>
    <div class="watermark" ng-show="!historyData.length">No upload
        history available</div>
    <div>
        <p>
            <img ng-src="{{contextRoot+'pics/addScanIcon.svg'}}"
                alt="addScanIcon"
                style="width: 25px; height: 25px; cursor: pointer" /> <span>
                Click the icon for a specific policy to upload additional documents
                to policy.</span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the html element being used as the input?

Comment: I've found that a dropdown arrow not being displayed is usually from a `::before` or `::after`  element not being displayed correctly. The element may be white or just hidden.

Comment: I am using <div id="historyGrid" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-edit ui-grid-cellnav ui-grid-move-columns ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-save-state ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-pinning ui-grid-grouping ui-grid-exporter class="grid"></div>

Comment: @user3224830 can you add the `html` code the the question session?

Comment: I just added HTML snippet to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working when I add below css

```
.ui-grid-pager-row-count-picker select {
    -webkit-appearance: menulist;
}
```

Or Just add background arrow image

```
.ui-grid-pager-row-count-picker select {    
    background-image: url("../pics/select_arrow.png");
}
```